# Web Scraping Google Result with R

Tags: r, web-crawler

I want to scape all the titles fo the result from google search.

For example, if I google 'asus', then I want to scrape all the title of the first page.

My problem is my result is empty.

The code is as below:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=asus'
first_page <- read_html(url)
title = html_nodes(first_page,'h3.LC20lb.DKV0Md') %>% html_text()
```

The reason why I use 'h3.LC20lb.DKV0Md' because I inspect the source code like below figure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55uNL.png)

Comment: Try the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/)

Comment: Thank Rohit. I will study it!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the class names on Google searches are not constant, so you need to use tag names instead of class names. I find it easier with xpath rather than css selectors:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=asus'
first_page <- read_html(url)
titles <- html_nodes(first_page, xpath = "//div/div/div/a/div[not(div)]") %>% 
          html_text()
titles <- titles[titles != ">"]
titles <- titles[titles != "View all"]
titles <- titles[nzchar(titles)]

df <- tibble(title  = titles[1:(length(titles)/2) * 2 - 1],
             url    = titles[1:(length(titles)/2) * 2])
df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   title                                url                                      
#>   <chr>                                <chr>                                    
#> 1 ASUS United Kingdom                  https://www.asus.com › ...               
#> 2 Asus - Wikipedia                     https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Asus   
#> 3 Asus Store: Computers & Accessories~ https://www.amazon.co.uk › Asus-Computer~
#> 4 ASUS - Amazon.co.uk                  https://www.amazon.co.uk › stores › ASUS~
#> 5 ASUS RMA                             https://rma.asus-europe.eu               
#> 6 ASUS Subreddit                       https://www.reddit.com › ASUS            
#> 7 ASUS Deals | Laptops Direct          https://www.laptopsdirect.co.uk › asus
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Allan! The solution seems work!
However, I will it on my Rstudio. I find out that the url column may contain some title rather instead of url.

The partial  result I tried as below([7]~[9] are title rather than url):
> x = df$url
> x                          
[6] "https://www.lenovo.com › Home › Laptops"                             
[7] "New Lenovo Ideapad S145-15IWL 81MV000LUS 15.6 HD Intel I3 ..."       
[8] "81MV000LUS - Lenovo Ideapad S145-15iwl 81mv000lus Notebook ..."      
[9] "Lenovo Ideapad S145-15iwl 81mv000lus Notebook - 81MV000LUS"

Comment: @AllanCameron Hi your answer was very useful, but I am not able to kodify your solution for a similar problem. Maybe could you please help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73178126/how-to-retrieve-titles-from-google-search-using-rvest