# My RSelenium code is not able to find web elements within frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler, rselenium

I am trying to write code that scrapes web content within a frame, also known as an iframe. I am using `RSelenium` for that goal. Here is the code I am using:

```
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
#Code
# using RSelenium to start firefox on the selenium server
remDr <- rsDriver(
  port = 4445L,
  browser = "firefox"
)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "firefox")
# open a new Tab on Chrome
remDr$open()
#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("http://www.emelnorte.com/docs8/html/factura3.html")
Sys.sleep(2)
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "vTIPODOCUMENTO")
webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
webElem2 <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option[3]")
webElem2$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
webElem3 <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "vNRODATO")
webElem4 <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "BUTTON1")
webElem3$clickElement()
```

The connection works fine but the issue rises when I try to get `webElem`, `webElem2`, `webElem3` and `webElem4`. I am getting this message (I will show only for `webElem` as the rest are equal):

```
Selenium message:Unable to locate element: #vTIPODOCUMENTO
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-4BLI75I', ip: '172.20.10.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_301'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

But when I explore the source of page:

[image]

I noticed I am setting the right id. So, anybody can please help if there is any way to get the web elements I need from this page or what I need to do to reach that goal.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are trying to access is located inside of an `iframe` tag, which means you have to first switch to that frame before using these otherwise correct `CSS` and `XPath` selectors. Insert these two lines of code after the `remDr$navigate` statement:

```r
myframe <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe")
remDr$switchToFrame(myframe)
```

Comment: Great! I will check and I will accept it!

Comment: Hi. I am having some issues with Rselenium, I do not know what is happening. I have posted as question, maybe could you give a check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708282/rselenium-is-not-working-when-creating-servers

Comment: @user007 Hello, I am not sure about this one sadly. It's probably a bug in the code. I see somebody else on GitHub has the same issue...

Comment: oh many thanks sir, do you believe if I start a bounty somebody could help?

Comment: Hi sir, sorry for wasting your time, months ago the solution you helped worked fantastic, today I tested again and is not returning any data. If you have any time, could you please check this question? Many thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735642/issues-retrieving-links-from-google-search-using-rvest

Comment: @user007 I am unsure how useful a bounty would be as the question is very niche and likely to do with the package development. And I am very happy to help you, no time helping others is ever wasted.

Comment: Hi dear I hpe you are fine. I just wanted to thank you for all help this year and I hope you have a marvelous 2023! I am here with a question related to selenium, If you have some time checking this it would be fantastic many thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953813/using-rselenium-to-download-a-file-embedded-into-a-frame