# RSelenium can't connect to host rsDriver()

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium, rsdriver

Until recently, I was using RSelenium without any problem. When I try to connect to hostr rsDriver() to start a selenium server and browser, I get the following error message:

```
Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 5111: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "firefox", port = 5111L, verbose = F) :
  Could not determine server status.
```

I have looked at some answers already proposed, like in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252080/rselenium-couldnt-connect-to-host-rsdriver/42253022#42253022). However, when I run the command,

```
> selServ <- wdman::selenium(verbose = FALSE)
> selServ$log()
```

I get the following error message:

```
$stderr
[1] "Error: Could not find or load main class c(-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\binman\\\\binman_chromedriver\\\\win32\\\\109.0.5414.25.chromedriver.exe\","
$stdout
character(0)
```

I tried to reinstall Java, but without success.

Comment: there might be a solution among the comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708282/rselenium-is-not-working-when-creating-servers or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74724087/rselenium-code-suddenly-not-working-without-any-updates-or-system-changes

Comment: @I_O unfortunately, this won't work...

Comment: I have the same issue here. I think something to do with the update on 4/12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I just solved the issue. The issue was that `RSelenium` recognises the `chromedriver` even when using other browsers so when the driver is not compatible to your current chrome version, it would have an issue with `rsDriver`. In order to solve this, you can either input `NULL` next to `chromever` or older chrome driver version from `C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32`

```
 rD <- rsDriver(port= sample(7600)[1], browser=c("firefox"), chromever = NULL)

 rD <- rsDriver(port= sample(7600)[1], browser=c("firefox"), chromever = 108.0.5359.22)
```