# Using RSelenium to download a file embedded into a frame

Tags: r, rselenium

I am working into a project where I have a web page that I need to click to get a pdf file. The file appears in a new window inside same page (I think is an iframe). Then I need to click on a button to download the file. The code I am using is next:

```
library(wdman)
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(selectr)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
#Code
#start RSelenium
# using RSelenium to start firefox on the selenium server
remDr <- rsDriver(
  port = 4445L,
  browser = "firefox"
)
#remDr$open()
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "firefox")
# open a new Tab on Chrome
remDr$open()
#navigate to your page
remDr$navigate("https://www.southtechhosting.com/SanJoseCity/CampaignDocsWebRetrieval/Search/SearchByElection.aspx")
Sys.sleep(2)
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_DefaultContent_ASPxRoundPanel1_btnFindFilers_CD"]')
webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
webElem2 <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_GridContent_gridFilers_DXCBtn0"]')
webElem2$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
webElem3 <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_DefaultContent_gridFilingForms_DXCBtn0Img"]')
webElem3$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(1)
#Move
myframe <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_GenericPopupSizeable_InnerPopupControl_CIF-1"]')
remDr$switchToFrame(myframe)
```

I think at this point everything works well but then I get the issue. I do not know if I am not able to move to the iframe (despite my code last lines worked), because this is what I get:

[image]

Now, I need to do click on the download button, but when I inspect that element, I am getting this:

[image]

I have searched and it tells that the element is hidden. Is there any way to make Rselenium do click on download?

I am asking about this because in a similar project, I am getting a window in same style but at the moment of inspecting I got this:

[image]

The button appears and I can copy the xpath, but I read in the description of element that is hidden in some way, so I think that is why my code can not find the element even after moving to iframe.

Any help would be very appreciated, I think if somebody can help me with the first example, I could solve my issue related to the second example explained at the end many thanks.

Comment: @KJ Many thanks! Could you provide an answer to solve the issue. I am thankfully with your smart comments but I do not understand how to translate into code!