# Scraping Google with rvest (2022 layout update)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

A few weeks ago people in this site helped me with a code to get links, titles, and text from a google search using `rvest`. Now, I am trying to use the same code as provided in:

[How to retrieve hyperlinks in google search using rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806861/how-to-retrieve-hyperlinks-in-google-search-using-rvest)

[How to retrieve text below titles from google search using rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215569/how-to-retrieve-text-below-titles-from-google-search-using-rvest)

And is not working, giving next results:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

#Part 1

url <- 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Mario+Torres+Mexico'

title <- "//div/div/div/a/h3"
text  <- paste0(title, "/parent::a/parent::div/following-sibling::div")

first_page <- read_html(url)

tibble(title = first_page %>% html_nodes(xpath = title) %>% html_text(),
       text = first_page %>% html_nodes(xpath = text) %>% html_text())
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: title <chr>, text <chr>
```

And second part:

```
#Part 2
titles <- html_nodes(first_page, xpath = "//div/div/a/h3")

titles %>%
  html_elements(xpath = "./parent::a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_extract("https.*?(?=&)")
```

Result:

```
character(0)
```

But in the past few weeks ago, this worked. Is it possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Google decided to change their HTML layout, perhaps there were too many of us scrapers.

Here you go:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

#Part 1

url <- 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Mario+Torres+Mexico'

title <- "//div/div/div/a/div/div/h3/div"
text  <- paste0(title, "/parent::h3/parent::div/parent::div/parent::a/parent::div/following-sibling::div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")

first_page <- read_html(url)

tibble(title = first_page %>% html_nodes(xpath = title) %>% html_text(),
       text = first_page %>% html_nodes(xpath = text) %>% html_text())
```

And part 2:

```r
titles <- html_nodes(first_page, xpath = "//div/div/div/a/div/div/h3/div")

titles %>%
  html_elements(xpath = "./parent::h3/parent::div/parent::div/parent::a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_extract("https.*?(?=&)")
```

Comment: It worked amazingly, many many thanks for your help. I have accepted and upvoted!